# Sending Multiple Email From GridView

Tags: asp.net

I hope some can help me on this issue.  The purpose of this email functionality is to send an email to individuals whose emails are listed in the GridView  with attached specific URL string in the email body.  I was able to send a multiple emails from the GridView and also pass the current query string in the URL in the Email body.  So everything is working fine up to here.  I have one challenge that could not resolve.   I want to include also  in the URL  the corresponding ID of email in the GridView.  Here is how my current URL look like:
//MyHost/BCA/Users/QMR.aspx?Post_ID=303

if my gridview look like this:

```
ID        Name              Email                       Post_ID
-------------------------------------------------------------------
32        Mike              xx@hot.com                  303
```

Then  I want to include the corresponding ID for this email in my URL like below and be able to send the URL to that user:
//MyHost/BCA/Users/QMR.aspx?Post_ID=303&ID=32

thanks

Here is my code:

```
protected void btnSendEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
     foreach (GridViewRow gr in GridView1.Rows)
     {
         CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.FindControl("chkItem");
         if (cb.Checked)
         {

             mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(GridView1.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex]["Assigned_To"].ToString()));
             mailMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["fromEmailAddress"]);
             mailMessage.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High;
             //Text/HTML
             mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = false;
             string mySubURI= HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString().Replace("Test.aspx", "QMR.aspx");       
             mailMessage.Body = "Hello, Please see this link" + mySubURI;
             mailMessage.Subject = "My Email Test";

             System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
             try
             {
                 smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

                 //Response.Write("<B>Email Has been sent successfully.</B>");
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 Response.Write(ex.Message);

          }
}
```

Comment: Is this a public site or an Intranet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
mySubURI += String.Format("&ID={0}", gr.Cells[0].Text);
```

With that you can access the first column (i.e. the ID) of each row in the gridview and append it to the end of your existing Url

Actually I assume this is the line you need the Url and if am wrong then next time, make it clear from your question where you need assistance

```
 string mySubURI= HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString().Replace("Test.aspx", "QMR.aspx");       
 mySubURI += String.Format("&ID={0}", gr.Cells[0].Text);
 mailMessage.Body = "Hello, Please see this link " + mySubURI;
```

Comment: Please explain, why the OP should try this!

Comment: I don't know but code-only answers are not really good answers. You should explain your solution, why it works and how it works.

Comment: Is that OK now? I should have used the comment instead

Comment: thanks guys.  codingbiz, where in my code should i add this line of code and my appology for not being smart when it come to coding; i am actually newbie and appreciate if you can help.  thanks

Comment: thank you so much codingbiz, you have no idea howmuch this was helpfull to me.  you guys rock...